# How does int map to IEnumerator<int> when implementing IEnumerator interface?

Tags: c#

For learning sake I am writing some sample programs and I have a question regarding IEnumerable's GetEnumerator method.

```
public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            //return new IterationSampleIterator(this); //C#1.0 getenumerator
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                yield return (int)values[i];
            }
            //yield return 1;
        }
```

In this case how is **int**
 being casted into 
**IEnumerator**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how is int being casted into IEnumerator

The integer is never cast to an IEnumerator. Notice the use of the `yield` keyword.

From msdn:

> When you use the yield keyword in a statement, you indicate that the
>   method, operator, or get accessor in which it appears is an iterator

and

> You use a yield return statement to return each element one at a time.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your int is not really being cast to an int. The method you show us here is supposed to return a set of int's. Not a single int.

By using `yield` you make sure the return type of your method is an `IEnumerable<object>` (i.e a collection of multiple int's).

But as you write in your method signature this gets implicitly cast to IEnumerable.